# Impedance matching for maximum power transfer

Tags: dc-dc-converter, impedance-matching, mppt

I have a simple circuit as below. Assuming that all components are ideal. With R2 and L1 are fixed, is there a switching frequency so that the voltage at node labeled VTH is constant (or relatively constant) and equal to V1/2 or 1.5V when switch is ON?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you would short pos to ground  at V2 when the switch is thrown.  IMO

Comment: I think what you want is a buck converter. If you operate it at 50% duty cycle you will get Vout = Vin/2 in the steady state. Transient response will depend on details. If you use real components, it may not be exactly Vin/2, but it will be close, and you can fine-tune the duty cycle.

Comment: Actually, this is the first part of boost converter and I am finding the optimum switching frequency so that during the ON switch, the energy from the source is transferred to inductor is maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there is no switching sequence that will make Vth constant or even roughly so.

With the switch open, the voltage will be V1.

When the switch closes, the voltage across the inductor will cause the current though it to increase, slowly increasing the voltage across R2, causing Vth to drop.

However, when the switch opens again, there is no path that the current can continue to flow, and the voltage will revert to V1.

You have almost drawn a buck converter. What it needs to finish it off is a diode from VD to V1. Then, when the switch opens, the current is allowed to continue to flow.

In the limit of a diode with zero drop, a 50% duty cycle will get you V1/2. The higher the frequency, the lower the ripple at Vth. As real diodes have a drop, the duty cycle will need to be offset a bit to compensate.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, this is the first part of boost converter and I am finding the optimum switching frequency so that during the ON switch, the energy from the source is transferred to inductor is maximum.

Comment: There is no optimum switching frequency, low means lots of ripple, high means higher switching losses. A higher frequency means you can use a smaller inductor for the same throughput power.I wonder if the R2 is confusing you?

Comment: I think you have a concept or two backwards. In a boost converter, you look at energy flowing in/out of the inductor on a  cycle by cycle basis. Although the switch goes on and off, 'frequency' is not really a useful concept. What matters is the time period the switch spends on, and off, for the build up and decay of current in the inductor. What's R2? Is it supply or switch loss, or your load? If you want to build a boost converter, it may be better to draw a boost converter and ask about that, rather than part of it and not address the real issues.

Comment: In that figure, R2 is internal resistance of the voltage source. I read a paper in which they choose the switching frequency so that maximum power is transferred to inductor in ON time. The optimum frequency is R2/8L. I want to proof that but it is not easy. Here is the link to the paper. Please see the formula (8) in page 5:
http://www.filedropper.com/abattery-lessthermoelectricenergyharvestingainterfacecircuitwith35mvstartupvoltagea

Comment: OK, I'm on my third readthrough of that paper, the fog is clearing slowly. tauN and tauP are not equal, and one of them is inversely prop to fs, so we are not talking about the clock at the switch, but the preiod of the output current flowing. BTW, showing M3 is important in the overall diagram, would have saved some confusion. If I have the time over the next few days I might try to get my head round the rest of it. Otherwise, I suggest you put the full circuit in a simulator and play with it. Not sure the authors have shown R2/vth in right place for my liking!

Comment: I think your question is pretty much dead in the water. What I would recommend is a) delete this question b) redraw your diagram, but left to right like in the paper (engineers like me read left to right!) and include M3 as a diode, and Csto, they're vital to understanding c) reference the paper in the OP d) label the voltages right, so vth = 50mV, Vsto >> vth, as the vsto>>vth condition is vital in the approximation of the power transfer equation, and engineers like and need context, the low volts is a good hook and ...

Comment: ... check my understanding the tauN is 1/2fs, and when you have, put that in the OP as part of the new question because it is the 'off' period, so the boost converter is operating like a conventional boost, e) I think vth and R2 are OK where they are, f) thinking about input impedance is an unusual way to look at it, which is why they've got a paper, and why it will take me a while to get my head around the conclusions they draw. You will have to point much more directly at the issues 'What fixed "off" time results in MPT?' to get the answers you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try to repost the thread once I make the question clear.